# A practical introduction to lambdaj?

Tags: java, lambdaj

[lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) seems like a nice project. What practical steps are needed to start using it? How do I integrate it with my Maven project?

Comment: Created issue: http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/issues/detail?id=52

Comment: I found answers to most of my questions in this document. It does not take maven into account though. http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures

Comment: @Flavio - it was a bit hard to find this among all the articles linked to from their main page. I'll give it a go.

Comment: I found this blog post very helpful in understanding how to use Lambdaj: http://harisupriyanto.blogspot.com/2012/09/using-lambdaj-list-of-example.html

Comment: Btw, here is an interesting slideshare http://www.slideshare.net/GenevaJUG/lambdaj-at-genevajug

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to use lambdaj in a maven project since it is available on the maven central repository as reported here:

http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/HowToBuildAndRelease

Comment: Actually, the article pointed to by @Flavio proved more helpful.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your question: I focused on the Maven part and I thought you were asking how to use lambdaj in Maven project. My advice is start from the slides of my presentation at JavaOne: 

http://lambdaj.googlecode.com/files/lambdaj-javaone-slides.pdf 

I hope the comparisons of pieces of codes doing the same things in plain java and using lambdaj could be a good starting point to figure the lambdaj's features out